# Function identity in Go

Tags: go, comparison-operators

How can I check the identify of a function in Go?

Suppose some code like this:

```
myCallback := func() { /* Do something */ }
someObject.Callback = myCallback;

// Then sometime later..

/* Has my callback been changed? */

if someObject.Callback != myCallback {
    log.Fatal("Someone changed my callback and didn't ask my permission!\n")
}
```

Of course, this specific code doesn't work. It complains that `func can only be compared to nil`.

So is there another way to do a function comparison to see if two functions (or function references--is that a thing in Go?) are the same?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643205/how-do-i-compare-two-functions-for-pointer-equality-in-the-latest-go-weekly

Comment: @DmitriGoldring: Perfect, thanks.