# What golang compiler will do when fmt.Println()

Tags: go, interface

I'm trying to understand how to check if two objects are the same when they implement the same interface.

Here is the example code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type shout interface {
    echo()
}

type a struct {}
func (*a) echo () {
    fmt.Println("a")
}

type b struct {}
func (*b) echo () {
    fmt.Println("b")
}

func compare(a, b shout) {
    //fmt.Println(&a, &b)
    if a == b {
        fmt.Println("same")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not same")
    }
}

func main() {
    a1 := &a{}
    b1 := &b{}
    a2 := &a{}
    a1.echo()
    b1.echo()
    compare(a1, b1)
    compare(a1, a2)
    compare(a1, a1) 
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qo9XnbthMw

The result is:

```
not same
not same
same
```

a1 and a2 are not the same

But if uncomment the line#22

```
fmt.Println(&a, &b)
```

The result is:

```
0x1040a120 0x1040a128
not same
0x1040a140 0x1040a148
same
0x1040a158 0x1040a160
same
```

Does anyone can figure out what happened here?
Does the Golang compiler optimize something?

Thanks

Comment: with or without  line#22, same result

Comment: sorry, i've update the code

Comment: add 
```
a1.echo()
b1.echo()
```
the result is not the same

Comment: I would post on [go-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts). In my opinion, there's something happening while optimizing.

Comment: @sounder do you have any idea after I update this code?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a more complicated example of https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8938.

The relevant parts of the Go spec are https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

> Pointers to distinct zero-size variables may or may not be equal.

and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees

> Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

Based on the title of the issue linked above (`cmd/compile: optimisations change the behaviour of *struct{}`), the difference is due to compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. For background, `==` is an operator which compares the *value* of two objects. This is known as object equality. Comparing their pointer value, or their identity, is different. See the top answer on [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643205/how-do-i-compare-two-functions-for-pointer-equality-in-the-latest-go-weekly).

When you ask `a1 == b1`, you receive `false` because `a1` is an instance of the `a` struct, whereas `b1` is an instance of the `b` struct. Therefore, even though they implement the same interface, they are *not* `==` to each other. Consider your `a` struct and `b` struct where they had additional and different methods implemented in both (so `a` has an additional method `foo()` and `b` has an additional method `bar()`). Although `a` and `b` would implement the same interface, they would not be the same, nor would you expect or want them to be.

When you ask if `a1 == a2`, you receive true because `a1` and `a2` are just separate instances of the same struct. Referencing the post I linked above, `a1` and `a2` are *equal*, but do not share the same identity.

Finally, when you ask if `a1 == a1`, you are asking if the same instance of the same object is equal to itself, which of course is true. In this case, `a1` shares both equality and identity with `a1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
Another question that I don't understand is why the fmt.Println() would change the result of the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `reflect.DeepEqual` to compare struct, slice and map.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type a struct{}

func main() {
    a1 := &a{}
    a2 := &a{}

    fmt.Printf("%p\n", a1)

    if a1 == a2 {
        fmt.Println("same")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not same")
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
0x196a9c
not same
```

Using `reflect.DeepEqual` as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type a struct{}

func main() {
    a1 := &a{}
    a2 := &a{}

    fmt.Printf("%p\n", a1)

    if a1 == a2 {
        fmt.Println("same")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("not same")
    }

    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(a1, a2))
}
```

The Result is:

```
0x196a9c
same
true
```

Just golang compiler optimization i guess.